# Clean an iOS system of all tracking information.

Tags: tracking

Would a factory reset permenantly remove all tracking information on an iPad or an iPhone?

Comment: It wouldn't change your IEMI, serial number, Bluetooth/WiFi MAC addresses, etc if you consider those to be tracking information.